# How to write tuples in a csv file in python with no blank line

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a couple of tuples to a csv file.

This is what I tried:

```
import csv
out_file = open('csv_write.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
writer.writerow((0, 1, 2))
writer.writerow((3, 4, 5))
out_file.close()
```

This worked, but not as expected. Notice the blank rows in a spreadsheet:

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet rows showing unwanted blank lines]

and in a text editor, the file looks like:

> 0,1,2
>   <*blank line*>
>   3,4,5
>   <*blank line*>

(total 4 rows)

How can I write without these blank rows?

Comment: Actually your code is working perfectly fine for me? Is there something else that you haven't shown in your example?

Comment: without using csv, change 'w' to 'a'. Then out_file.write("0,1,2 \n") and so on

Comment: @ViktorKerkez No, this is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `csv` module does its own end-of-line handling, and requires the output file to be opened in a specific way:

```
out_file = open('csv_write.csv', 'wb')             # Python 2.x
out_file = open('csv_write.csv', 'w', newline='')  # Python 3.x
```

Reference http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer:

> ...it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

And http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer:

> ...it should be opened with newline=''...

Your blank lines are due to the default "dialect" of the `csv` module being `excel`.  That dialect defines `lineterminator='\r\n'` and those characters are written directly to the stream.  Opening the output file in text mode on Python 2 or without `newline=''` on Python 3 "on platforms where that makes a difference" (Windows) translates all `\n` in the output stream to `\r\n`, resulting in `\r\r\n`.  This causes your extra blank rows.